# slimScroll- doesn't work good in the second modal

Tags: javascript, slimscroll

I have 2 modals (when the first is close the second is open) the code of the first modal in a template (gsp) and the of the second one is in  the view page

The code I use for close the first and open the second is:

```
    function openModal(){
        if($('.invitePartners').valid()){
            $('.invite-contacts-modal').modal('hide')
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            $('#mySecModal').modal();
}
```

The html for the second modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mySecModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog signup-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title light-green"><g:message code="signup.redesign.invitepartners.modal.title"/></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <g:message code="signup.redesign.invitepartners.modaldetails.header"/><br><br>
            <span>${user?.firstname}</span><span> ${user?.lastname} </span><g:message code="signup.redesign.invitepartners.modaldetails.body"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="signup-button back pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><g:message code="buttons.dontsend"/></a>
            <button name="next" class="signup-button skyblue-btn pull-right pl-pr-36" >${message(code:"buttons.ok")}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the first modal the scroll works fine.
I the second modal the user can scroll until he get to the end of the modal (which is cut).

I use scrollSlim plugin

Comment: What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: That the scroll will be on the modal not on the page itself